# Fastest way to determine whether a uni-variate integer polynomial is positive semi-definite or not.

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, roots, computational-complexity, positive-semidefinite

What is the fastest way to determine whether a uni-variate integer polynomial is positive semi-definite or not? This question seems to be fundamental but I could not find an answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

In Maple, you could use the sturm function to determine the number of real roots.  The function is positive semidefinite if the value at one point is positive and all real roots have even multiplicities.